# Edit google maps style without changing maps code

Tags: google-maps

I'm not programmer and I design in Adobe Muse. I have added widget with Google Maps - it works with no problem. I want add to this Maps black and white effect. I don't have access to widget code but I can add every code to html file. It is any chance to change style of this Maps ?

This is site preview: http://adr805.webd.pl/sample/

I have the code to this but I don't know how to implement this without edit widget.

```
[
  {
    "stylers": [
      { "saturation": -100 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: How specifically have you tried to use this, and how did it not work as expected? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Answer (score 0):

For black and white you can add some CSS to the main DIV that renders the map. For example:

```css
    .sepia {
           -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
    }

   .blackwhite {
         -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(10%) contrast(100%);
    }
```

```html
<div id=map_canvas class=blackwhite></div>
```